# How to check if Python venv is active in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, command-line, python-venv

I am looking for a way, from within either Windows CMD or Powershell, to check if a Python virtual environment has been activated. In Bash, it is possible to use this conditional to check if a venv is active.

```
if [[ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]]
```

I've also seen this done in Bash, and I could probably get it to work on Windows, but it feels like a hack and, as much as we all like a good hack, I feel like there ought to be a better way.

```
PYTHON_ENV=$(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('1') if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') else sys.stdout.write('0')")
```

Is there any documented, straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course I figured out a way to do this shortly after asking the question here, but I'll post this as an answer here since I couldn't find this info anywhere else on the site. As expected, Powershell (and probably CMD, though I didn't test it myself) gets an environment variable set, `$VIRTUAL_ENV`, when a virtual environment is active. This can be easily tested for in a Powershell script with the following conditional:

```
if (Test-Path env:VIRTUAL_ENV) {...
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there

Answer (score 0):

In Bash script (on Ubuntu 18.04, with python3) to detect then activate the python virtual environment if necessary...

```
if [ -z ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ]; then 
    echo "VIRTUAL_ENV is is ..."; 
    source ./venv/bin/activate
    echo "ready."
fi
```

Unfortunately it also deactivates the virtual environment in the script I have written.

senox13's answer above gave me the idea.